# How to make List view for items in Android?

Tags: android

Please help me out here. I need to make a **list view** as shown in the sample pic for my **android app**. How to do it? Also I need to add **image** along it as seen in the sample pic. and link it to another view to show some more details.please check links shown below.

[image]

[pic1](http://www.cellnxt.in/temp/smp.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

First create a layout for your list item in layout/list_item.xml (or any name). **I've shown only text field for the item, but you can change the view below to include both image and a label.**

```
  <TextView xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       a:layout_width="fill_parent"
       a:layout_height="wrap_content"
       a:textSize="14dp"
       a:paddingBottom="5dp"
       a:paddingTop="5dp">
   </TextView>
```

Define a listView in another layout e.g. layout/list.xml

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       a:layout_width="fill_parent"
       a:layout_height="fill_parent"
       a:orientation="vertical"
       a:stretchColumns="1">
     <ListView a:id="@+id/paramList" a:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           a:layout_height="fill_parent" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

In your activity get the handle to list view and add data to it.

```
 // Find the list view component in your layout.
 ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paramList);

 // obtain data
 List data = ... //some list data

 // use a list adapter to render your list item in your list view!!
 // The item is rendered using the list_item.xml layout.
 // Here you can have any layout, with image and text as in your pic.
 ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, data);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html). BaseAdapter defines a getView method, which will return the view that will be used by the list items. You can create the view diagrammatically or load it from XML. Then in your ListActivity you use the setListAdapter method.

See an example [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/).

Comment: If the data is in a list use an ArrayAdapter instead BaseAdapter. If it comes from a Database use a CursorAdapter.